Create a route (Laravel 10 - Nuxt 3 )
[nuxt] error caught during app initialization Error: Page not found:
/password-reset/46f9fe46fc92949ec48113486813cdd5f03add89f6d9cae0a983c2511a863097?email=ospreystudio2020@gmail.com
link that needs to be made on the front end
ResetPassword::createUrlUsing(function (object $notifiable, string $token) {
return config('app.frontend_url')."/password-reset/$token?email={$notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset()}";
});
pinia store:
async resetPassword(data) {
            try {
                const response = await $axios.post('/reset-password', data)
                this.status = response.data.status
            } catch (error) {
                this.error = error.response.data.message
                console.log(this.error)
            }
        },

pages->pasword-rest->_token.vue
_token.vue
`<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { usePasswordResetStore } from '@/stores/passwordReset'
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const store = usePasswordResetStore()
const route = useRoute()
const router = useRouter()

const form = ref({
  token: route.params.token,
  email: route.query.email,
  password: '',
  password_confirmation: '',
})
const resetPassword = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await store.resetPassword(form.value)
    console.log(response)
    router.push('/')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('*****', error)
  }
}
</script>`

nuxt.config.ts
`router: {
    mode: 'history', 
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'password-reset',
        path: '/password-reset/:token',
        component: '@/pages/password-reset/_token.vue'
      }
    ]
  },`

I don't understand the error. Why the route was not built and how to understand where it is being built
